# Personal blog hosting, based on Java Servlet technology

Tags: java, blog

I would like to run my own [blog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blog) site on my own server, to be hosted on [Java Servlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_servlet) technology. I can run on either [Apache Tomcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat) (a [web container](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_container)) or [Payara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payara_Server) (full [Jakarta EE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform%2C_Enterprise_Edition)) servers.

I need to host at least one blog (my own), and possibly a few other individuals.

I do not know enough to make specific requirements, except that my needs are quite simple. I just need to be able to author and edit remotely via a web browser. I do not need a fancy/complicated “content management system”. I just need a quick way to write and publish short articles. I need to include images (JPEG or PNG), so an upload feature for that. And embedding YouTube videos might be nice, but optional.

Should support a standard blog posting protocol such as [Micropub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micropub_(protocol)), [Atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(Web_standard)), or [MetaWeblog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MetaWeblog).

The only special feature is that I need to be able to post source-code in a monospaced font. Automated fancy-formatting of displayed source code would be icing on the cake.

Comment: [A list of open-source blog software in Java](https://java-source.net/open-source/bloggers), but seems to be out-of-date.

Comment: [This Answer](https://superuser.com/a/54676/212610) on sister site SuperUser.com suggests [Pebble](https://github.com/pebbleblog/pebble).